# Is it proper to refer to objects beyond Neptune as "Kuiper Belt Objects?"

Tags: solar-system, kuiper-belt, trans-neptunian-object

It seems to me that nowadays the more proper term is "Trans-Neptunian Object".  Is there any difference between Kuiper Belt Objects and Trans-Neptunian Objects?  If not, is one term preferred over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a difference, Kuiper Belt Objects (KBOs) are a subset of Trans Neptunian Objects (TNOs). Other subsets are Oort-cloud objects (OCOs) and scattered disk objects (SDOs). These are not KBOs but they are TNOs. See for instance this [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Neptunian_object#Distribution_and_classification).

Answer (score 0):

So to refer to objects beyond Neptune you use 'trans-Neptunian objects'. It really sounds simple, there are several sub-sets of trans-Neptunian objects: referring to minor-planets (neither Planets nor comets) that exist in this region of the Solar System.